# What bore a hole in this rose?

Tags: pests, roses, pest-damage, bugs

There is a hole in this rose. What is the name of the bug that would create such a hole?

[image: A rose with a bore hole in it.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of damage is usually caused by a bee, earwig or other insect trying to get at the nectar/pollen inside the flower; drilling through the side in this way gives access prior to the flower opening up. Depends what part of the world you're in as to which insect is responsible.

Comment: We are in British Columbia, Canada.